# How can I customize Eclipse editor generated by xtext

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext

In my current project, I am trying to provide an outline view in my editor. I have written the following grammar in xtext:

```
Model:
    (vocSpec=VocSpec );


VocSpec:
    structKeyword = 'structs' ':' (structs+=Struct)+
    resourceKeyword = 'resources:'  
     sensorKeyword ='sensors' ':'
    periodicSensorKeyword ='periodicSensors' ':' (periodicSensors+=PeriodicSensors)*
    eventDrivenSensorKeyword ='eventDrivenSensors' ':' (eventSensors+=EventSensors)*
    requestBasedSensorKeyword ='requestBasedSensors' ':' (requestSensors+=RequestSensors)*
    tagKeyword ='tags' ':' (tags+=Tags)*
    actuatorsKeyword ='actuators' ':' (actuators+=Actuator)*
    storageKeyword ='storages' ':' (storageService+=StorageService)* 
    ;

Struct:
    name=ID (fields+=Field)+;

Field:
    name=ID ':' type+=Type ';'
;

/* Periodic Sensor Definition */
PeriodicSensors:
    sensorName=EntityName
    (generateInfo+=Generate)+
    'sample' 'period' INT 'for' INT ';'
;

/* Event Driven Sensor Definition */
EventSensors:
    sensorName=EntityName
    (generateInfo+=Generate)+
    'onCondition' (eventConditions+=EventConditions) ';';

/* Request Based Sensor Definition */
RequestSensors:
    sensorName=EntityName
    ((DataAccess+=DataAccess))*;

/* Tag Definition */
Tags:
    sensorName=EntityName
    (generateInfo+=Generate)+;

EventConditions:
    name=ID ('>' | '<' | '=')* (intValue=INT) (nameUnit=Unit) (',' eventConditions+=EventConditions)?
;

OPERATOR:
    opt='>' | opt='<' | opt='=';

EntityName:
    (name=ID);

Generate:
    'generate' sourceName=SourceName ':' type=Type ';';

SourceName:
    name=ID;

Actuator:
    actuatorName=EntityName ((actions+=Action))*;

Action:
    'action' actionName=ActionName '(' (parameters+=Parameters)* ')' ';';

ActionName:
    name=ID;

Parameters:
    parameterName=ParameterName ':' type=Type;

ParameterName:
    name=ID;

/*  Storage Service Definition  */
StorageService:
    storageServiceName=EntityName
    ((dataAccesses+=DataAccess))*;

DataAccess:
    'generate' sourceName=SourceName ':' dataAccessType=Type
    'accessed-by' dataItem=ID ':' type=Type ';'
    ((actions+=Action))*;

/* Type Definition */
Type:
    (primitiveDataType=PrimitiveDataType);

Unit:
    name='PPM' | name='miliseconds' | name='seconds' | name='minutes' | name='ppm';

PrimitiveDataType:
    INTEGER='Integer' | BOOLEAN='boolean' | STRING='String' | LONG='long' | DOUBLE='double' | structDef=[Struct];
```

With the above grammar, I write the following specification:

[image]

Here, `Sensors` is **a type of** `Resource`,  `periodicSensors` is **a type of** `Sensors`. `Tags` is a type of `Resource`, `actuators` is type of `resources`. 
 So, If I convert this into an outline view, the outline view should be as follows:

[image]

However, with the above grammar I am getting the following outline view in the editor generated by xtext. How can I get my desired outline view in the xtext editor. I guess that I have to modify my xtext grammar as described above? / Other thing. Kindly advise

[image]

Comment: I'd adopt the OutlineTreeProvider and not the grammar

Comment: @ChristianDietrich : I also face the similar problem. could you please advise it little bit more detail. This would help me to find solution.

Comment: e.g. like https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1067193/